# Extract heading and content from an HTML page using a visual approach in Python

Tags: python, html

I'm looking for a way to extract the heading and content from raw HTML. There are a couple of Python packages out there which does this (Newspaper3k, python-readability, python-goose), but I'm looking to do something more like how the human eye sees. My idea is to use the visual placement of a div on a page to determine if it's part of the main content of a page or not. How can I extract the placement of a `div` using python? Any other ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: does that help you? https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding, you want to locate and extract html from certain divs from a website, but on screen, with a cursor and a keyboard (like a human would do), for that purpose, you could go with **PyAutoGui**.

You can use `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()`, with a parameter of choice, you can then advance with scrapping tools.
With PyAutoGui, you can automate click events as well.

For further research, you can check the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Hope this answers your question, if doubts, please feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks @Strange - I'll have a look later today or tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: I had a look, @strange but I don't think this will be the most efficient option for me. You did bring up another idea for me though, which is to turn the HTML into an image and then use that image to determine the location on the screen.

Comment: Hey @Muriel, I got a glimpse of what you maybe referring to about the idea, sounds good, in case you choose to go with former approach and encounter any problem, feel free to ask, if the later idea works, please feel free to share any update ( sounds interesting enough, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the worst part of the Python packages you mentioned is the required HTML and DOM structure knowledge.  Nevertheless, it is necessary for scraping I can share a **hybrid approach**.

**First step:** I use [WebScraper.io](https://webscraper.io/documentation/selectors/text-selector) Chrome extension to visually select items on the page (like on the image) and save them.  [image: An example visual selection]

**Second step**: Once I have DOM selectors like `p a.cta` (on the image). I use them with the Python scraping package.

I use this approach almost for any scraping project. I hope it helps.